# Default product filtering (Woocommerce layered nav filters)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am trying to set a default filter in the product archives - when the page is loaded to be filtered by default by an attribute.

I tried to set a select value on load, with JQuery, but obviously this thing happena only on the select element in frontend.

Do you know any plugin that has the ability to set a filter by default (atribute) or a workaround in php that sets the desired filter on load?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the default layered nav widgets from WooCommerce. The key is to found out which URL is generated when you pick the options you want to have selected by clicking on these. An URL should be shown in your address bar similar to;

http://asdf.com/shop/?filtering=1&filter_attribute=1234

Copy this URL and replace the link to your shop archive - assuming it is in your menu - under Appearance > Menus in the WordPress Dashboard with a Custom Link that points to this URL.

Hope this helps you out, good luck!